# Whats wrong with this JavaScript if statement?

Tags: javascript

The function runs when the user presses enter in the textbox (`KeyCode === 13`) but i cant get it to work with `searchButton`

```
function myFunction(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 13 || document.getElementById("searchButton").click()){
        e.preventDefault();
        var searchValue = document.getElementById("mySearch").value;
        for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
        if(users[i]['last_name'] === searchValue){
        document.getElementById("return").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(users[i]);
        return;
        }
     }  
  }
}

<input type="search" id="mySearch"  onkeypress="myFunction(event)" />
<button id="searchButton" onclick="myFunction(e)">SEARCH</button>
```

Is the problem the `||` expression? The function should run either when the user presses `searchButton` or presses enter.

Comment: JavaScript `.click()` always returns `undefined`

Comment: check for `e.type == 'click' && this.id=='searchButton'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The call to `document.getElementById("searchButton").click()` is a programmatic way to simulate a click.

What you probably mean to do is:

```
function myFunction(e) {
    if((e.target.id === 'mySearch' && e.keyCode === 13) || e.target.id === 'searchButton'){

    }
}
```

Comment: **Update** This does not work for some reason... I have no idea why as it seems like it should totally work... [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hpjvkgqw/)

Comment: There was a missing parenthesis... sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so when you press the enter key `myFunction` is called with an event which has the keyCode property, so that is all good.

When you click the button though, the event does not have a keyCode property, and therefore the right side of your conditional `document.getElementById("searchButton").click()` runs. `click` is a method that [simulates a mouseclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click), returning undefined. So the conditional resolves to false, and the rest of the function body will not be run.

You could instead check the type of the event.